# Dataview Sort Date by Month and day

Tags: sql, sorting, dataview

I'm looking to sort a DataView by Day and Month to create a list of birthdays for an organization, and am looking to sort using DatePart.  I can achieve this within the SQL, but the sort order does not persists into the dataview from the returned results and using this won't work.

```
DataTable dt = dsResults.Tables[1];
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

dv.Sort = "DATEPART(Month, birthdate),DATEPART(Day, birthdate)";
dt = dv.ToTable();
```

i'm not very familiar with dataviews or the sort method, so any help is appreciated

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I've read the documentation, i know they only accept asc and desc within the sort method, i guess I was more wondering if someone knew a way for me to achieve this functionality

Comment: Nick in the documentation it shows sorting on multiple columns which is what you want view.Sort = "Month ASC, Day ASC" .  If you are saying because you don't have columns then create a sort column or columns in your dataset and hide those in the dataview from displaying

Comment: Or just a thought because you may not want to show year you could switch to MM/dd format and sort on your birthday column.

Answer (score 0):

The DataView.Sort() will sort based on data type in column. 
The trick is to add a properly formatted temporary column to your data table to sort on.

This temp column method is faster than you'd expect.

Expanding the code from your question above
eg:

```
DataTable dt = dsResults.Tables[1];

//add a sorting column
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SortySortColumn", typeof(string)));

//enumerate all the rows 
DateTime oTMPdate;
foreach (DataRow oDR in oDT.Rows)
{
    //test for date, if date convert to two letter month, two letter day
    //  add that value to the sorting column
     if(DateTime.TryParse(oDR["birthdate"], out oTMPdate)
         oDR["SortySortColumn"] = string.Format("{0:MMdd}", oTMPdate);
}       

//sort by our new temporary column
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "[SortySortColumn] ASC";
dt = dv.ToTable();

//remove the temporary column
dt.Columns.RemoveAt(dt.Columns.Count - 1);
```

Don't overlook the power of string.Format() you can do a heck of a lot with it. :-)